# Why I get empty POST in server from Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have array in Angular JS:

```
$scope.formData.conditions
```

Before AJAX request I display this varaible:

```
[1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", 4: "4", 5: "5"]
```

But on server PHP I get array like as:

```
["conditions"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
```

Why element with index 2 is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's not an array, that's an object. Server-side you then convert it to an array. This conversion process is the problem. Send it as a dictionary (`{1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", 4: "4", 5: "5"}`) and PHP will know to convert it into a sparse array (which is a dictionary too).